# How to create a component for a html code in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I have this code:

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
   <input id="txtboxid" type="text" v-model="full_name">
   <label for="txtboxid">Middle Name *</label>
</div>
```

And I have lots of those with different ID's and model's and my html file looks big. Is there a way to make it shorter in vuejs? Like just a single line and it will have those? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, put your IDs and names into an object or an array, loop them by using v-for. IDs could be set by using v-bind.

Comment: @choasia ha! I like that idea.

Comment: See [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/ajy0e03c/) with Vue . Enjoy!

Comment: Dude @AbdennourTOUMI I need to use Vue for this for some purposes. Thanks for the recommendation btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have pointed out in the question, itself, you can create re-usable [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#ad) in `Vue.js`, for using  the same HTML template again and again. You can create a simple vue [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Registration) from your code as following:

```
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '\
   <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6"> \
   <input :id="id" type="text" v-model="value"> \
   <label for="txtboxid">Middle Name *</label> \
</div> \
  ',
  props: [
      "id", "value"],
  watch: {
    value: function(newVal){
       this.$emit('input', newVal)
    }
  }
})
```

and it can be used in your HTML just by using single line:

```
<child v-model="full_name" id="24"></child>
```

Please check working fiddler [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/ajy0e03c/).

In the above code I am using [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), you can also use [event handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) on change `@change` to get the `full_name` updated in the parent, demo [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/ajy0e03c/1/).

**Some Explanation:**

I am using [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) here. `<input v-model="something">` here, which is essentially syntactic sugar for:

```
<input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
```

You can use this to create components and send your varaible in `v-model` and accept it in the component as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props).

Comment: I think a specific event handler (such as `v-on:input`) would be better than `watch`. Nice answer though

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your recommendation, I have changed the code, please have a look [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/ajy0e03c/1/).

Comment: Did you see the warning message in the console whenever you type something in the textbox? @Saurabh