# How to use v-model in place of v-bind?

Tags: vue.js

here is a working custom component:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yavj0en/)

```
 <myselect :option="cnt" ></myselect>
```

above code works, now how to change it into v-model? following code won't work:

```
  <myselect v-model="cnt"></myselect>
```

how to use v-model in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a component for a html code in Vue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151272/how-to-create-a-component-for-a-html-code-in-vue)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a possible solution, but seems different, that one uses template while mine uses render function.

Comment: You can use the "cnt" variable which in your case will work like v-model.

Comment: this code uses v-model='cnt', but it shows an undefined error in Chrome chonsole: https://jsfiddle.net/4yavj0en/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

```
<input v-model="something">
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
<input :value="something" @input="something = $event.target.value">
```

In your fiddle you are still referencing an `option` property, but the component no longer has one. You need to reference the `value` property to get the initial value of `cnt` and then emit an `input` event to update the `cnt` var being used as the model. https://jsfiddle.net/4yavj0en/2/

Comment: if v-model='something' is just syntactic sugar for :value='something', why this sample does not work,   <myselect v-bind="cnt" ></myselect>, https://jsfiddle.net/4yavj0en/4/

Comment: when using `v-bind`, you need to specify the property you are binding to. Like `v-bind:value="cnt"`